# How to make changes on hover that save on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change a text color when hovering on squares, and then keep that change on click.

I used jQuery ; the squares are divs that have the `ho` class:

```
$('#bg1').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $('span').css("color","orange");
    },
     mouseleave: function(){
        $('span').css("color",$('#currentColor').css("color"));
    },
    click: function(){
            $('.ho').on('mouseleave');
        $(this).off('mouseleave');
        $('#currentColor').css("color","orange")
    }
});



$('#bg2').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $('span').css("color","magenta");
    },
     mouseleave: function(){
        $('span').css("color",$('#currentColor').css("color"));
    },
    click: function(){
            $('.ho').on('mouseleave');
        $(this).off('mouseleave');
        $('#currentColor').css("color","magenta")
    }
});
```

**Just see the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ZqfTX/868/**

It works at first : when I click on a cube, it keeps the text color, and when I hover out of that cube to see the other hover points (without click), I see their effects, and moving out returns well to the color of the clicked cube.
But, when clicking on the other cube and testing again : it all breaks..

Why could this be happening ?

Comment: Your fiddle works fine when tested with clicks on both cubes, what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'it all break'. Seems to be working logically to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the: `$(this).off('mouseleave'); && $(this).off('mouseleave');` in your click functions.

```js
$('#bg1').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $('span').css("color","orange");
    },
     mouseleave: function(){
        $('span').css("color",$('#currentColor').css("color"));
    },
    click: function(){
    // $('.ho').on('mouseleave');
    //    $(this).off('mouseleave');
        $('#currentColor').css("color","orange")
    }
});



$('#bg2').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $('span').css("color","magenta");
    },
     mouseleave: function(){
        $('span').css("color",$('#currentColor').css("color"));
    },
    click: function(){
    //    $('.ho').on('mouseleave');
      //  $(this).off('mouseleave');
        $('#currentColor').css("color","magenta")
    }
});
```

**Here is the working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZqfTX/871/

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with this

```
    $('#bg1').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $('span').css("color","orange");
    },
     mouseleave: function(){
        $('span').css("color",$('#currentColor').css("color"));
    },
    click: function(){
        //$('.ho').on('mouseleave');
        //$(this).off('mouseleave');
        $('#currentColor').css("color","orange")
    }
});

$('#bg2').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $('span').css("color","magenta");
    },
     mouseleave: function(){
        $('span').css("color",$('#currentColor').css("color"));
    },
    click: function(){
        //$('.ho').on('mouseleave');
        //$(this).off('mouseleave');
        $('#currentColor').css("color","magenta")
    }
});
```

When you click and execute:

```
$(this).off('mouseleave');
```

The function inside:

```
mouseleave: function(){ // code }
```

Don't work anymore, because are you removing the event handler
and only can execute mouseover handler, because of that, it set the
color when you hovering.

For more information:
http://api.jquery.com/off/